# Check if a string contains only specified characters including underscores

Tags: string, bash, character

I want to receive a string (one word) from the user, with the following criteria: The string may contain only alphabetical characters (aA-zZ) and underscores.  Digits and other characters are not allowed.

How may I do this in BASH?

Comment: by character do you mean alphabetical characers? `[A-Za-z]`? Because by definition, everything in the String is characters...

Comment: Can you please show us what you've already tried?

Comment: What code do you have so far? What seems to be going wrong with it? Have you read the manpage for Bash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `=~` to check a string against a (POSIX extended) regex. See manpages `bash(1)` and `regex(7)` for more.

```
# assume your string is in variable $s
if [[ $s =~ ^[A-Za-z_]+$ ]]; then
  # it matches
else
  # doesn't match
fi
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this code works. The manpages are not so clear. What does the =~ and the +$ actually do?

Comment: What if I want to allow also white spaces?

Comment: @Khaleal, ask Google for a regular expression tutorial and you'll make it. Or try the link above your comment.

Comment: @Khaleal escaping with a slash works for me: ^[A-Za-z_\ ], but the same doesn't seem to be holding true for a dash...

Comment: @Jordan what about `^[A-Za-z_\ -]+$`? Dashes need to be at the front or end inside the `[ ]` class.