# How to check that string contains only blank (\t\n ) characters?

Tags: string, bash, shell

How to check in bash that string contains only blank characters as space, tab, new line? I'm trying this but it doesn't work:

```
if [[ "$1" == @([\t\n ]) ]]; then
   echo "Empty"
fi
```

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349938/how-can-i-check-if-a-variable-is-contains-only-letters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763980/check-if-a-string-contains-only-specified-characters-including-underscores/20764037

Comment: I've trying this: if [[ "$1" == @([\t\n ]) ]]; then but it doesn't work

Comment: Why `@`? Why `(` `)`?? The answer there does `[[ "${line}" =~ [^a-zA-Z] ]]`. So you want `[[ "${line}" =~ [^\t\n ] ]]`... You can learn regex easily with https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: `if [[ "$1" =~ [\t\n ] ]]; then; echo "Empty"; fi`
This code produce syntax error

Comment: `[[ $1 =~ ^[[:space:]]+$ ]]`

Comment: @Shawn : Maybe you should put this as answer. Looks to me as best solution.

Comment: The semicolon after `then` is also a syntax error. You can fix the syntax error from the regex by backslashing the space; though I would perhaps regard `[[ "$1" = *[!\t\n\ ]* ]]` as a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular expression:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^[[:space:]]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Only whitespace"
else
    echo "There are non-whitespace characters."
fi
```

Use `*` instead of `+` if you also want to match empty strings.

Comment: A pedantic nitpick... this will report non-whitespace characters for an empty string. Unlikely if reading lines, but I'd still rather use an asterisk and group "nothing" with whitespace-only, unless the specific need *requires* there to be a character - then I'd make 2 checks (one for whitespace, one for non-whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to an array, it will be empty if string contains only blank characters

```
string="    "
array=($string)
[[ ${!array[@]} ]] && echo fail || echo ok
```